Oracle OEM 13.4 OMS httpd.conf ssl.conf admin.conf mod_wl_ohs.conf WebLogic SSL Listen Port connection
I have Oracle OEM 13c ( 13.4) and it was working fine. We have to reboot server due to memory issues and later on when we tried to restart oms, web tier was not coming up. Eventually we have found out that DemoIdentity & Trust certificates were expired so that was taken care.
However, we have issues with console URL https
e.g
Console URL: https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com:7802/em
Does not work and it redirects to https://b-oem-grid.mydomain.com:7802/omsunavailable.html
I see following message
Enterprise Manager Cloud Control is not currently available.
The EMGC_OMS server where Cloud Control runs, or some other component, might be down.
httpd.conf has #[Listen] OHS_LISTEN_PORT
Listen 7788

ssl.conf has following port
#[Listen] OHS_SSL_PORT
Listen 7802
....
 #[VirtualHost] OHS_SSL_VH
 <VirtualHost *:7802>
  <IfModule ossl_module>
   #  SSL Engine Switch:
   #  Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
   SSLEngine on

admin.conf has
Listen 127.0.0.1:10006
#[VirtualHost] OHS_PROXY_VH
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:10006>

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
      WebLogicHost db-oem-grid.mydomain.com
      WebLogicPort 7301
      Debug ERR

From weblogic admin console
I have configured SSL listen port for EMGC_OMS1 to 7301
EM console is working on weblogic port e.g. https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com/em:7301/em
However it does not work https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com/em:7802/em ( 7802 was in ssl.conf)
emctl status oms -details also shows console URL to https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com/em:7802/em
What is causing issue ?
I am not sure whether some thing is wrong with http.conf, ssl.conf, mod_wl_ohs.conf and weblogic  ports
does ssl.conf port 7802 supposed to redirect to weblogic SSL port 7301
Our previous configuration before cert expiration was working fine and OEM URL was working fine too https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com/em:7802/em
Thanks for help.

It looks like I had these lines commented our during debugging of OMS issue and forgot to uncomment that
After I uncomment, my https port ( defined in ssl.conf ), It is working fine
https://db-oem-grid.mydomain.com/em:7802/em
# SecureProxy On
  # WlSSLWallet "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/fmwconfig/components/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/instances/${COMPONENT_NAME}/keystores/proxy"
  # WebLogicSSLVersion TLSv1_1 TLSv1_2

